# Ground drone schematic and PCB review

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, circuit-design, raspberry-pi, design

I am creating a small ground drone and have come up with the following design:

[image: schematic]

To control the motors I use MOSFETs driven by proper drivers, while I also placed a GPS module (L80-M39) and an accelerometer (ADXL357BEZ), both for motion correction.

Before ordering any printed circuit board though I would like to have an opinion on the design, regarding correctness.
I'm more perturbed about the MCU and power delivery part.

Any advice to improve/correct it is welcome!

Following the advice in the comments I fixed the schematic and added the PCB layout below.

[image]

Top layer:
[image: top layer]

Bottom layer:
[image]

Comment: Consider zeners on motor drive FET gates rated at slightly above V_drive_max. These clamp possible Miller coupled spikes from inductive loads (which should be caught by the drain-supply protection diodes, but ...).

Comment: Overall, your schematic is quite good, but there's a few places where you could tidy it up and improve the readability. Eg Q1/4 mosfets drawn sideways, D4/5/6/7 should be vertical. What is K2? A relay? Needs a better symbol. There's no diode on the coil if that is the case. F1 is not really needed unless you have 3V3 going off board. F2 could be better placed. A transzorb on the input for over/reverse voltage would make F2 do a better job. One critical component is the pcb layout - be very careful with component selection (esp the ceramic caps) and understand where your currents are flowing.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKsx5.png

Comment: Please show the PCB layout, including power planes.

Comment: Tony Stewart EE75 Thank you. I updated the question with some of your advices and I added some informations about the components.

Comment: Bruce Abbott Done.

Comment: Please avoid cutting up your planes with long tracks. Consider vias or a wire.

Comment: winny what net do you mean specifically? How would you intend to use vias?

Comment: Your ground pour, especially on bottom layer. Instead of one long trace, alternate on top and bottom layer to avoid creating long continuous cuts in your ground plane.

Comment: Tip: to ping someone use the `@username` syntax with all spaces removed.

Comment: thank you @winny

Comment: Zener on the Drain is redundant with a shunt diode. @RussellMcMahon suggested Z on the Gate . Compute what is the power dissipation in your diode and temp rise?  What do you expect if Vf on diode is 0.8V and Vds on FET when each conduct?  Russ ought to explain better his reasons.  My advice is specify the R in each component. e.g. 1W diode ~ 1 Ohm , Motor DCR=,  FET Ron= then compute temp rise.

Comment: The Z is redundant where you have it and diode will be hotter than FET. Russ pls explain your suggestion with more detail

Comment: @tony & lab3tas: My zener suggestion was GS connection & not on drain. This is based on long ago practical experience in situations with inductive loads where spikes should notionally have been well suppressed but FETs died. Miller capacitance couples drain spikes into the gate and can cause gate destruction. I found that clipping gate spikes in this way allowed circuit to run indefinitely even in situations  where they otherwise died in minutes. I've used them with inductive loads ever since. This is "belt & braces" and may not theoretically be needed. But, in practice ... :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  I understood, but others may not and may be worthy of a detailed answer from you or reference App Note to save time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems some explanation is needed here that driving motors with small power is different from large motors.  Since you have not specified the load current or motor, you must be the judge if your open drain driver with clamp (flyback) diode is adequate.

### Flyback diodes

When power dissipation is small, the higher Rs of diodes can tolerate the higher loss due to higher Rs= slope of V/I at V > Vf nominal. At these currents you can treat the diode as a switched resistor, just like FET's except typically much higher resistance.  When using high PWM frequencies,  the decay time constant is relatively long, longer than 1/f for T=L/R.

- When using a power motor with large L and low R= DCR of coil + Rs of diode
  , the Pd=I\$^2\$R loss is too much for a diode and a low RdsOn FET must be used instead.
- This is called a Half Bridge like a SPDT switch with nearly equal low resistance on each switch for low loss.
- When driving motors in both directions, then it is called Bridge Tied Loads using a Full bridge driver or DPDT configuration.
- Often the capacitance of the bridge must be considered vs risetime of current and drive voltage { Sch/Si/SiC diode, MOSFET, DFET, CMOS, IGBT  increases with conductance Y=1/R) therefore this adds to the driving load and (not here) but in future you must consider the technology suited best for each bridge voltage, current and speed. Each technology has a family or familar T=CR range suited for different applications.

### Half Bridge

The better solution, but depends on load specs of Z, V, I,f, dV/dt, L, DCR and budget for low cost toy or 100W practical limit for flyback SMPS.

There are too many types to mention here. TL/DW.

The other critical design issues are copper pour heatsink temperature rise and ground paths design.  In the interest of brevity, I only give key words for your research.

Power Dissipation of PCB depends on copper weight for buffer energy storage, thermal vias, surface area and temperature rise. 1 , 2 sided and 1,2,4 oz copper.

Treat power-switch ground current like you would Logic or digital ground such that gate-drive ground current is treated like signal or Analog ground. **They must not share current** to your hopefully almost ideal voltage source due to ground noise and parasitic inductance.

Answer (score 1):

I see the question was updated today. I wonder if you run into problems with this PCB, because there is a problem with the return path for some signals, especially in the top left corner.

[image: Joined top and bottom layer]

As you see, the traces on the bottom layer (GND) cut the plane (from Datalogger to U6) at places where a lot of signals route from left to right. (Originating U3).

This means that especially for the higher speed signals (100 kHz and above, and with a short risetime) some interference between the signals could happen, because the expected return plane is broken. A mayor part will travel around U6 on the bottom plane and datalogger.

Also because of the distance between top and bottom layer, a bigger distance between the signals is recommended.